# Running Total in Matrix Rows

Tags: powerbi

I have incremental data elements that I want to summarize.  I'm pulling the incremental data into a matrix object just fine, but I need to summarize them by cumulating across columns (within the Row)

What I'm seeing:

```
Column:    1       2       3       4       5
Row     |-----------------------------------------
1       | 10      15      5        4        1
2       | 12      12      3        1
3       | 10       9      6
4       |  9      15
5       | 11
```

What I want to see:

```
Column:    1       2       3       4       5
Row     |-----------------------------------------
1       | 10      25      30       34      35
2       | 12      24      27       28
3       | 10      19      25
4       |  9      24
5       | 11
```

What I've tried, this just returns the incremental data (as if I just pointed it to [INC_AMT]:

```
Cum_Loss = CALCULATE(
SUM('Table1'[INC_AMT]),
FILTER(All (Table1[ColNum]), Table1[ColNum] <= max(Table1[Column])))
```

Comment: So, the value at Col5 Row2 is Blank and not just 28 again?  What would happen if there were blanks in the middle of your data set -- like at 2,2?

Comment: First Question:
For my purposes, it's best if it's blank (it represents a time in the future that hasn't happened), but it's possible that I could add a condition to force it to be blank in the event that Row + Column < 7 (for this example)

Second - and maybe getting more clarity into the first, blanks within the data should be treated as zeros...  So maybe treat all blanks as zeros then filter the visuals on the backend?  Not sure.

Comment: I thought the blanks were going to be a problem but they aren't.  See my solution below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this measure a try:

```
PERIODIC INCREMENTAL SUM = CALCULATE
(
    SUM('TestData'[INC_AMT])
    , FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(TestData)
        , and(
            TestData[ColNum] <= max(TestData[ColNum]) 
            , TestData[RowNum] = max(TestData[RowNum])
        )
    )
)
```

I found it helpful to not think about the measures in a matrix perspective.  Transform it to a table and you see that one way to think about it is that it's just a cumulative sum where 'Row Number' is also the same.  So, add that requirement to your filter and... presto.[image]